# Why use node providers? Is it necessary to use them for small project?

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, web3-providers, alchemy

I want to start a small project and consider to run own node for it.
The other day, I just found there are node providers like **Alchemy**, **Infura**, and so on.
I just did their tutorials, and I think it is easy to use.
But I want to know their pros and cons in real dev environments.

If you guys don't mind, could you share your experience using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [can easily run your own node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513)

- You need 24/7h computer
- SSD with NVMe is needed for IO speed
- Cost can range between ~$20/mo - ~$150/mo depending on your hosting cost (electricity, hardware)

[Check the node provider list here](https://ethereumnodes.com/) - there are also some limited free APIs.

Comment: This website is a nice resource but I did notice that the numbers are not updated often and it doesn't disclose where the nodes are and how they are tested, so I don't think the numbers are too representative at this moment.

Comment: It is an open source website. If you think you any information is missing or outdated you can [submit a pull request here](https://github.com/dmihal/ethereum-nodes).

Answer (score 1):

Overall running your node is very labor and resource intensive, especially for a small project. You'll end up spending thousands for the hardware and weeks to sync up a new node.

This article about [full vs archive nodes](https://chainstack.com/evm-nodes-a-dive-into-the-full-vs-archive-mode/) gives an overview about the main challenges and why using a node provider makes sense.

There are many node providers and almost all of them offer **at least one node for free**.

- Some pros of using a node provider is that you will always have someone to maintain the node for you and you can just contact someone in case you have issues.
- Cons are that some providers limit what you can do on their free plans.

I recommend [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/). Easy to set up, fast nodes, great support, many APIs available, and supports [many different chains](https://chainstack.com/protocols/), I'm a dev advocate for them.

- [Create an account on Chainstack](https://docs.chainstack.com/quickstart/create-an-account)
- [How to deploy a node on Chainstack](https://docs.chainstack.com/quickstart/deploy-a-network-or-a-node)

They also have a very good page in the docs with a lot of [JSON-RPC API call examples](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/node-api-reference) in web3.js, web3.py and some other languages.

Comment: I suggest  you edit your question and disclose your affiliation based on [ethereum.stackexchange.com policy](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: I did not notice that policy, I will!